# Extract a certain file from an archive with 7-Zip from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, archiving, extract, 7-zip

If I have an archive, for example, `some.zip` that contains one or more files, how can I extract only one file (I know the name of the file) with [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) from the command line in Windows?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You just add the filename at the end.

```
7z e [archive.zip] -o [outputdir] [fileFilter]
```

Comment: How can I add multiple file filters, say `.XML` and `.zip`? Sorry if I'm hijacking this thread,  I just didn't want to add a duplicate question.

Comment: It's a different question @Fr0zenFyr. To make it clear that it is not duplicate, you can reference this question in your own, and then specify how yours is different.

Comment: @music2myear: Thanks for clarification. Top voted answer by zionyx already includes a solution. My comment is over 2 years old, so it would be a reasonable guess to assume that I either used above solution or already posted a question and found an answer (BTW, this was my case). My [resolved post is on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24339419/1369473) and original thread created before my comment is [here](http://superuser.com/q/770255/243637) so I couldn't link to this question. :)

Comment: Note : as it is written here, do not put space between -o and outputdir.

Answer (score 57):

As a follow-up to [surfasb's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/321829/extract-a-certain-file-from-an-archive-with-7-zip-from-the-command-line/322233#322233), add a -r flag at the end to recurse:

```
7z e [archive.zip] -o[outputdir] [fileFilter] -r
```

Multiple filters support:

```
7z e [archive.zip] -o[outputdir] [fileFilter_1] [fileFilter_2] -r
```

Example:

Multiple filters command line:

```
7z e archive.zip -o outputdir *.xml *.dll -r
```

PS: I use 7za.exe instead of 7z.exe. This is the actual command I use in my script:

```
7za.exe x archive.zip -o outputdir *.xml *.pdb *.exe *.ocx *.dll -r
```

Comment: How can I add multiple file filters, say `.XML` and `.zip`? Sorry if I'm hijacking this thread,  I just didn't want to add a duplicate question.

Comment: Should be fine by separating the filters by space. See the edited answer above. :)

Comment: And how do I extract a specific file from an archive inside the archive? Lets say the file I'm looking for is "MyFile.txt" inside "SubArchive.zip" inside "MainArchive.zip". Is this possible?

Comment: @PeterCo, I think the command is only capable to extract `SubArchive.zip` from the `MainArchive.zip` in your case. You may run a follow up command to extract `MyFile.txt` from `SubArchive.zip` after the initial extraction.

Comment: You also want to double-quote those wildcard filters, e.g. "*.exe" or "*.pdf". Without that, the filter will skip filenames with embedded space characters.

Comment: Useful: use `7z x` instead of `7z e` to keep the directory structure when extracting.

Answer (score 9):

If you look at the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z) for 7z you will find that the following command can be used to extract a file from a 7z archive (though the usage of path is missing from the man page):

```
7z x <archive> <path to file>
```

Examples:

```
7z x backup.7z *.html
7z x backup.7z folderwithin/myfile.html
```

Alternatively you could use `e`.

The [command line version users guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/) seems to have more information on the actual usage.

Comment: Is that the relative path within the archive?

Comment: Yes, the "folderwithin" is a folder at the root of the archive.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `7z` has the following syntax (observe the spaces and quotes surrounding the `"-oMy Folder"` option to set the output folder name, took me hours to figure out, as I originally did this – the wrong way: * `-o "My Folder"` *):

```
7z e "my zip.zip" "-oMy Folder" *.jpg "all of these.*" -r
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I found that on zsh command line, with 7-zip 16.06, that I had to put double-quotes around the wildcard filter argument. For example, this **did not** find any PDF files to extract:

```
7z e "archive has pdf in subdirectory.zip" -r *.pdf
```

but quoting the wildcard filter **did** find and extract the PDF file that was in a subdirectory of the zip archive, like this:

```
7z e "archive has pdf in subdirectory.zip" -r "*.pdf"
```