# Recursively process zip archives to extract files while discarding specific format of files

Tags: windows-7, windows, compression, zip, recursive

***UPDATE:*** I noticed that many people are viewing this thread, which makes me believe that this situation is not so rare after all. Anyway, I had asked a similar/related question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24339419/1369473), which has pretty decent solutions too which might solve the problem in a better way.

On my Windows 7 machine,  I have a directory full of downloaded dumps in ZIP archives.  Each archive contains few text files, PDFs and rarely XML files.  I want to extract all the contents of each ZIP archive into its respective folder(must be created during the process) while discarding/ignoring extraction of PDFs.  After extraction of required files from an archive,  processed zip **must not** be deleted(or I would like to know how I can control it in different situations).

If it helps to know, the number of archives in the directory is in the range of 60k-70k.  Also,  I need separate output directories because files in an archive may have same names as files in other.

For example,

- I have all my archives like `one.zip`, `two.zip`,.. in, say, `D:\data`
- I create a new folder for processed data, say, `D:\extracted`
- Now the data from `D:\data\one.zip` should go to `D:\extracted\one`.  Here,  `D:\extracted\one` should be created automatically.
- During this complete uncompression process,  all the encountered PDFs should not be extracted(be ignored).  There's no point in extracting and then deleting.
- ***(Optional)*** A log file should be maintained at, say, `D:\extracted`.  Idea is to use this file to resume processing from where it was left in case of an error.
- ***(Optional)*** Script should let me decide whether I want to keep source archives or delete them after processing.

I already did some search to find a solution but couldn't find one.  I came across few questions like these

1. [Recursively unzip files where they reside, then delete the archives](https://superuser.com/questions/620056/recursively-unzip-files-where-they-reside-then-delete-the-archives)
2. [7 zip extract recursively](https://superuser.com/questions/248287/7-zip-extract-recursively)
3. [Is it possible to recursively list zip file contents with 7 zip without extracting](https://superuser.com/questions/596715/is-it-possible-to-recursively-list-zip-file-contents-with-7-zip-without-extracti)

but they were not of much help(I'm not a pro with Windows by the way).  I'm open to installing **safe and ad free** 3rd party software(open-source) like 7-zip.

**EDIT:** Is there a tool readily available to do what I need,  I already tried [Multi Unpacker](http://code.google.com/p/multiunpacker/). It doesn't create new directories,  it can't ignore *.pdf files.  It's even slow to start with,  I think it first reads all the archives at source before starting to process them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any way around this without a batch or powershell script, as far as I know there is no out-of-the-box solution for something like this.

Comment: @private_meta thanks for your response.  I had already guessed it by now,  but it's good to be sure.  Can you point me in the right direction for writing a powershell for this.  I also understand that ignoring PDFs during extraction is a huge challenge,  so I'm ready to let the script extract everything and then delete the PDFs.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/q/321829/243637

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the answer found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/620056/recursively-unzip-files-where-they-reside-then-delete-the-archives), this piece of PowerShell script should do what you want. Just save it as a file with the Extension ".ps1". When calling it, just call it as ./filename.ps1  and it will extract the files to separate folders, delete the zip files and remove all files with .pdf extension. I have not tested if it works properly with recursive paths, but it should, please test it.

**Edit:** If you don't want your zip files to be deleted, remove or comment out (#) the line `rmdir -Path $_.FullName -Force`

Requirements: PowerShell, 7-zip and for you to set the 7-zip path in the file.

```
param([string]$folderPath="D:\Blah\files")

Get-ChildItem $folderPath -recurse | %{ 

    if($_.Name -match "^*.`.zip$")
    {
        $parent="$(Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent)";    
        write-host "Extracting $($_.FullName) to $parent"

        $arguments=@("e", "`"$($_.FullName)`"", "-o`"$($parent)\$($_.BaseName)`"");
        $ex = start-process -FilePath "`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe`"" -ArgumentList $arguments -wait -PassThru;

        if( $ex.ExitCode -eq 0)
        {
            write-host "Extraction successful, deleting $($_.FullName)"
            rmdir -Path $_.FullName -Force
            $arguments1="$($parent)\$($_.BaseName)\*.pdf"
            rmdir -Recurse -Path $arguments1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of asking you to help me modify the code from same answer,  you are a mind reader.  I will try this code and report the progress here.  I'm really glad you took time to read my question carefully and covered almost every aspect of it.

Comment: You can use it as a basis and modify as needed. The part about not extracting pdf files in the first place is a major challenge, I don't think it would work with normal tools.

Comment: Also, if you use more than one "param", you need to call them like this: "./script.ps -folderPath path -delete" and so on. For switches, refer to [this](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/12/20/using-powershell-switch-vs-boolean-parameters-in-sma-runbooks/)

Comment: Thanks mate,  I tip my hat to you.  This script achieved almost everything that I wanted(except the log file thing).  Since there has been no better answer than this,  I accept your answer as the solution.  Ohh,  and BTW, by default my system's PowerShell didn't allow me to run the script saying it is disabled.  I had two choices,  either signing the script or executing `set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in PowerShell as Administrator.  I tried both and they worked,  though the 1st is better choice but out of this comment's scope to explain why.

Comment: Hi again,  the script worked beautifully except in one case I found out.  Few of my zip files had sub folders,  the script extracted the folder and placed its contents parallel to it(outside sub-dir). Can this be fixed somehow?  Also,  I had few files which were `.tar` and `.zip` inside them,  so what should I replace `if($_.Name -match "^*.'.zip$")` with to process them recursively? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you replace `$arguments=@("e",` with `$arguments=@("x",`  it should preserve directory structure, please test that.

About recursive extraction, I don't know if it works properly like that, but what you can do is have the script call itself with a new directory, in this case every subdirectory. If there is a zip file in a root location of the folder, it will unpack it. Otherwise, it will get a lot more complicated. I'm not good enough with powershell though.

Comment: I started disliking Power Shell now,  it seems confusing and complicated.  I'm trying to manage this with a batch script now,  I already did much of it in just 1 line. Thanks mate for the reply though. I just posted a [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24339419/1369473),  you can see my progress there.