# Report All Files Hierarchically on a Zip-of-Zip Files from the Command-Line Interface

Tags: command-line, zip, winzip

I have a WinZip parent file that contains hundreds of WinZip child files on a Windows 7 64-bit computer. Each child WinZip file has many "grandchild" files within it. I need to create a text file non-verbose report of all the exploded files: the child files, and the grandchildren files within each child.

Using the command-line (Version 4.0 64-bit [Build 10562]), one can create a text report of the children files, but not the embedded files within each child:

```
wzzip /vb MyFileFamily.zip > MyFileFamilyReport.txt
```

The WinZip tool or the command-line interface both offer ways to report the child files, but not the embedded files additionally. How do you create a full report of all the files within the zip-of-zips from the command-line?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're going to do this without writing some kind of script that works in a loop to temporarily extract the contents of each zip and report on it.

Comment: Agreed, considering this similar answer: http://superuser.com/questions/770255/recursively-process-zip-archives-to-extract-files-while-discarding-specific-form/770270#770270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Swiss File Knife](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html) will allow you to do this from the command line in Windows.

sfk list -arc MyFileFamily.zip > MyFileFamilyReport.txt